# Sort array middle to low to high

Tags: java, sorting

I have a list of points which I first sort ascending on the x value. Now I'd like to sort the list again based on the y-value but from middle to low to high (or middle to high to low, doesn't really matter).

This is my java code:

```
Collections.sort(list, Comparator.comparing((Integer[] p) -> p[0]).thenComparing(**"middle to low to high"**));
```

For example:

Initial list: `{(10,9),(11,8),(10,5),(10,7),(8,9),(11,9)}`

First sorting: `{(8,9),(10,9),(10,5),(10,7),(11,8),(11,9)}`

Second sorting:  `{(8,9),(10,7),(10,5),(10,9),(11,8),(11,9)}` **this is where  I need help**

Is there a way to write a comparator for this?

Thank you!

Comment: You'll have to define middle, low and high first.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than trying a new Comparator, change the numbers. Say your interval is (0..12), middle is 7, then the easiest way is to change all values >7 to v-13, sort the result and change back by adding 13 to all negative values.